# how to preserve this keyword in below scenario

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on backbone app. I am adding `mousedown` event using backbone which calls `select` function. Inside `select` function I am setting `timeout` which calls another function `selection`. In `selection` function I want to console `currently clicked element` using `console.log(this.el)`. However, `this.el` is undefined because the this does not refer to my current module. **How can I preserve this keyword so that I can use this in selection function?**

Here is my code

```
    events: {
        'mousedown': 'select',
        'mouseup': 'deselect'
    },


    select: function () {
        this.timeoutId = setTimeout(this.selection, 1000);
    },

    deselect: function () {
        clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
    },

    selection: function () {
        console.log(this.el);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve it like this:

```
select: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        self.selection();
    }, 1000);
}
```

Many browsers also support the `bind` function, which binds an object as `this` to a function

```
select: function() {
    this.timeoutId = setTimeout(this.selection.bind(this), 1000);
}
```

Comment: @downvoter - Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var self = this;
self.timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
    self.selection();
}, 1000);
```

Or:

```
this.timeoutId = setTimeout(this.selection.bind(this), 1000);
```

Reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind